# rotating image on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am completely new to this so bear with me. I am looking to rotate the main image on this page http://jovanatanackovic.com/index.html every time its refreshed or loaded. I found this and tried adding it in the script tags

```
function random_imglink(){
  var theImages = new Array()

  theIimages[1]="images/thalia-heffernan-4.jpg"
  theImages[2]="images/volcano-surfing-the-ascent.jpg"
  theImages[3]="images/rooster-fighting-sucking-blood-from-face.jpg"
  theImages[4]="images/cooper-canyon-fallen-tarahumara.jpg"
  theImages[5]="images/copper-canyon-finishers.jpg"

  var j = 0
  var p = theImages.length;
  var preBuffer = new Array()
  for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
    preBuffer[i] = new Image()
    preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
  }
  var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

  function showImage(){
  if(whichImage==0){
    document.write('<a href =""><img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'" border=0 width=689 height=466></a>');
  } else if(whichImage==1){
    document.write('<a href ="link.html"><img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'" border=0 width=689 height=466></a>');
  } else if(whichImage==2){
    document.write('<a href ="link.html"><img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'" border=0 width=689 height=466></a>');
  } else if(whichImage==3){
    document.write('<a href ="link.html"><img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'" border=0 width=689 height=466></a>');
  } else if(whichImage==4){
    document.write('<a href ="link.html"><img src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'" border=0 width=689 height=466></a>');
  }
}
```

and I was told to add this where I wanted the images to show

```
<script>showImage();</script>
```

is this correct? I'm sure sure where exactly to put it as the current image has css attached. I've tried adding it inside the div tags.

Comment: Try to use CSS-animations combined with CSS-rotation (transformation).

Comment: "rotate" is a poor choice of words. I think everyone thinks you want the image to spin.

Comment: I did :P Was just making this awesome rotation thingy :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/AQQ44/)

**CSS**

```
#imgTest {
    background-image: url('YourImage.jpg');
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: right;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: rotate;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-direction: right;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: rotate;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-direction: right;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-name: rotate;
    -o-animation-duration: 4s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-direction: right;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: right;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -ms-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imgTest"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure that the OP meant that kind of "rotate".  Rather that a different image is shown on each page load.

Comment: Maybe the OP will implement it anyway ;)

Comment: Who doesn't want stuff to rotate on their website? :P I have the feeling I'm getting "pitty-upvoted" :P

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use that code, then you want the following:

```
<div class="photo">
  <script>
    ...JAVASCRIPT HERE...
  </script>
</div>
```

Of course, it would be a much nicer solution to use javascript like the following instead of document.write:

In the HEAD:

```
<script>
function showImage()
{
  // Better array init thanks to Joseph Silvashy
  var theImages = [
    "images/thalia-heffernan-4.jpg",
    "images/volcano-surfing-the-ascent.jpg",
    "images/rooster-fighting-sucking-blood-from-face.jpg",
    "images/cooper-canyon-fallen-tarahumara.jpg",
    "images/copper-canyon-finishers.jpg"
  ]

  var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));

  document.getElementById("rotatingImage").src = theImages[whichImage];
}
</script>
```

and

```
<body onload="showImage()">
...
```

Comment: Don't you mean `theImages[whichImage]`?

Comment: To go further, you could add a timeout function that would change the image after so many seconds. If you did this, you'd want to drop the "random" number, and just iterate from 0-4 each time.

Answer (score 0):

As a tip, you could simplify the array:

```
var theImages = [
  "images/thalia-heffernan-4.jpg",
  "images/volcano-surfing-the-ascent.jpg",
  "images/rooster-fighting-sucking-blood-from-face.jpg",
  "images/cooper-canyon-fallen-tarahumara.jpg",
  "images/copper-canyon-finishers.jpg"
]
```